# Can't store time over 9 hours and 10 minutes

Tags: time

I am making a clock on my Arduino Uno using the time library http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Time

I let the user set a time. Which is then converted to seconds and used in the

```
setTime(s);
```

function.
When the value is over 9:10h, the seconds evaluate to 4 294 941 360 seconds (=
1 193 039.27 hours)

A code snippet:

```
void timeChange() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Change time");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("00:00");
  int hoursSet    = 0; //Stores the hours added.
  int minutesSet  = 0; //Stores the minutes added.
  String printTime;
  bool timeComplete = false;
  while (!timeComplete) {
    int buttonVal = analogRead(A0);
    if (buttonVal >= 490 && buttonVal <= 520) { //Indicates button 3 is pressed. It's function is to add one hour to the time.
      hoursSet = (hoursSet + 1) % 24; //Adds one hour to the hours.
      delay(100);
    } else if (buttonVal >= 5 && buttonVal <= 10) { //Indicates button 4 is pressed. It's function si to add 5 minutes to the time.
      minutesSet = (minutesSet + 5) % 60; //Adds minutes to the minutes.
      delay(100);
    }

    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    String strHr = String(hoursSet);
    String strMn = String(minutesSet);
    if(strHr.length() == 2){
      lcd.print(hoursSet);
    } else if(strHr.length() == 1) {
      lcd.print("0");
      lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
      lcd.print(hoursSet);
    }

    lcd.setCursor(2,1);
    lcd.print(":");
    lcd.setCursor(3,1);
    if(strMn.length() == 2){
      lcd.print(minutesSet);
    } else if(strMn.length() == 1) {
      lcd.print("0");
      lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
      lcd.print(minutesSet);
    }
    delay(100);

    if (buttonVal >= 990 && buttonVal <= 1010) { //if button 2 is pressed again, the timecomeplete is set to true, and the script continues.
      timeIsSet = true;
      timeComplete = true;
    }
  }
  lcd.clear(); //Clear the screen
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("The time"); //Print text, move cursor and print the time
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  String strHr = String(hoursSet);
  String strMn = String(minutesSet);
  if(strHr.length() == 2){
    lcd.print(hoursSet);
  } else if(strHr.length() == 1) {
    lcd.print("0");
    lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    lcd.print(hoursSet);
  }
  lcd.setCursor(2,1);
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.setCursor(3,1);
  if(strMn.length() == 2){
    lcd.print(minutesSet);
  } else if(strMn.length() == 1) {
    lcd.print("0");
    lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
    lcd.print(minutesSet);
  }
  lcd.print(" is saved!");
  setTime((hoursSet * 3600) + (minutesSet * 60));
  timeIsSet = true;
  delay(5000); //Wait five, seconds then proceed
```

}

Added this to the code:

```
      Serial.print("hours ");
  Serial.println(hoursSet);
  Serial.print("hours in s ");
  Serial.println(hoursSet * 3600);
  Serial.print("minutes ");
  Serial.println(minutesSet);
  Serial.print("minutes in s ");
  Serial.println(minutesSet * 60);
  Serial.print("Combined:  ");
  Serial.println( (hoursSet * 3600) + (minutesSet * 60) );
```

When I input 5:15 it results in:

> hours 5
>   hours in s 18000
>   minutes 15
>   minutes in s 900
>   Combined:  18900

When I input 9:15 it results in:

> hours 9
>   hours in s 32400
>   minutes 15
>   minutes in s 900
>   Combined:  -32236

So, it looks like the library only holds an Int. But that seems odd, as the function expects seconds.

Comment: And now you know why no one does that.

Comment: Well, this is a school project due tomorrow. So I can't do much with this...

Comment: What IDE version are you using, that page you've referenced specifically states it doesn't work with 1.61

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hint: 32767 seconds is 9 hours, 6 minutes and 7 seconds.

What is the largest value that an `int` can hold?

---

EDIT: I can't add comments on this computer (old browser), so I have to respond to your question here.
`time_t` is an unsigned 32-bit value, but all of your input values are signed 16-bit values. When you take a product like 3600*10, you get a bit pattern of `1000110010100000`, which is 36000 when interpreted as an unsigned value, but is -29536 when interpreted as a signed value.

When assigned to a `time_t`, the value is sign-extended to 32 bits, which makes it `11111111111111111000110010100000`, which is 4294937760 when interpreted as an unsigned value.

If you want to write a statement like

```
time_t x = (hoursSet * 3600) + (minutesSet * 60);
```

you need to type-cast your input arguments to the correct type first:

```
time_t x = ((time_t)hoursSet * 3600) + ((time_t)minutesSet * 60);
```

Comment: Well, I know that is. But as it is a function "setTime" Which expects a second input for the time. And also would take a date like that.

Comment: Can I edit the function so that it takes unsigned long?

Comment: time_t x = (hoursSet * 3600) + (minutesSet * 60);
      Serial.println(x);
      
      
      setTime(x);

When I try it like that, it returns Combined:  4294937760 (For 10:00)

Answer (score 0):

Changing this:

```
  time_t x = (hoursSet * 3600) + (minutesSet * 60);
```

To this:

```
  time_t x = ((unsigned long)hoursSet * 3600) + (minutesSet * 60);
```

Has solved the problem